# Is everytime need to precompile the asset when we change the css or js file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a basic question in asset.

```
1. Is everytime need to precompile the asset when we change the css or js file.
2. When pre-compiling old css and js files  servered or not?
i have checked the local when pre-compiling no css loaded.
3.Is it necessary to precompile the asset in development mode to work in local.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some problems understanding your english, but maybe I understand what you are asking for.

It works like this:

When you are working in development mode on your local machine and edit stylesheets or javascripts, Rails and the Asset-Pipeline take care of reloading the relevant files. No Precompilation will happen.

When you deploy to a server in production, the `rake assets:precompile` task will create all the asset-files for you, so that you can serve them via a webserver like apache or something and rails does not need to handle it.

I think that with Rails4 the pre-compilation-process is much quicker, because it does not compile files that did not change, but I am not 100% sure about that.